# Using linux sed command in python os.system

Tags: python, linux, sed

I am having trouble using the sed command with `os.system()`

```
path= "/backup/verify/2020-11-19_test_pg_basebackup_daily_verify/postgresql.conf"
sed = "sed -i.bak 's/^\(port = \).*/\15437/' "+path
print(sed)
os.system('{}'.format(sed))
```

I print the `sed` to see what's going wrong and this is what I get:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(port = \).*/l37/' /backup/verify/2020-11-19_test_pg_basebackup_daily_verify/postgresql.conf
```

Why the `5437` changed? also when I try to write the whole command in the `os.system` without using the string `sed` I get this errors:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./func.py verify 2020-11-19_test_pg_basebackup_daily
  File "./func.py", line 56
    os.system('sed -i.bak 's/^\(port = \).*/\15437/' /backup/verify/2020-11-19_test_pg_basebackup_daily_verify/postgresql.conf')
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do numbers in a string become "x0n" when a backslash precedes them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146891/why-do-numbers-in-a-string-become-x0n-when-a-backslash-precedes-them)

Comment: you have quotes inside quotes. What do you expect? Use python features & regexes instead of running an external (non portable) command.

Answer (score -1):

Python (as many other programming languages) use the backslash `\` as a special character inside strings, to produce characters that are otherwise tricky. A well known example is `'\n'` for new line. It turns out that `\1` is also interpreted as something special. To tell Python to understand your string *literally* as what you typed, use the `r` prefix:

```py
sed = r"sed -i.bak 's/^\(port = \).*/\15437/' "+path
```

Here `r` stands for either "*r*aw" or "*r*egex (*r*egular expression)", the latter being a common use case.

Comment: _Here r stands for either "raw" or "regex (regular expression)"_: no it's just "raw".