# After split why is it adding \t here and \x08? How to avoid this conversion?

Tags: python

```
>>> output = "10.1.1.2\11.1.1.2$11.1.1.2\10.1.1.2"
>>> output.split("$")
['10.1.1.2\t.1.1.2', '11.1.1.2\x08.1.1.2']
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with `split`.  Take a look at `output` itself in your interactive shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do numbers in a string become "x0n" when a backslash precedes them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146891/why-do-numbers-in-a-string-become-x0n-when-a-backslash-precedes-them)

Comment: You did not use raw strings. In a normal string the escape sequence `\10` (oct) is equivalent to `\x08` (hex). And printing a list shows the escaped version of the strings contained in it.

Answer (score 5):

Split isn't adding anything, you are. `\11` is character octal 11 (decimal 9), which is tab. `\10` is character octal 10 (decimal 8), which is usually written `\x08`. They're already in `output` before the `split`.

If you want backslashes in your string, write them as `\\`, or use a raw string, `r"10.1.1.2\11.1.1.2$11.1.1.2\10.1.1.2"`.